# TypeInitializationexception -filenotfoundexception

Tags: c#, .net, gac, .net-4.6.2

I seem to be having odd issues with one of my assemblies,
So my program was working fine in Net4.6.1, but i had to upgrade to 4.6.2 as this is the new target framework. Also the references went to a new location from program files x86 to program files.

However doing this gave me an typeinitializationexception, when debugging a little further we seem to come across a filenotfoundexception of one of my dependencies log4net.

all de dll are added trough references-add reference ->external location

by some miracle i had made it back to work in debug mode but not in release mode.

AS i discovered in release mode same issue, so I tried to put my dlls in root folder where the exe is an not my dependencies folder and it seems to work. SO my guess is that even tough i specified a url trough adding the references it keeps searching in the root directory of the exe.

Any idea why and how i can fix this kind of problem?

The only solution i have tried is by creating a new project and copy my code in it-> same issue.
The reason why we put all our dependencies in a seperate folder is to prevent version mismatch.? and in this project we have several dll's that are used with multiple version old ones for the main program and new ones for this project which are added to gac.

Comment: If you use visual studio to do a "rebuild all", do you get any build errors (output panel, or error list panel)?

Comment: no i don't get any errors at all

Comment: It sounds like you have this error when you run it from your server, but not when you run it locally from VStudio. Is that correct?  If so, how are you deploying it to the server? (copy of bin folder, or publish command or build server handles it?)

Comment: the server is also loca, i do clean solution and then build in release, then goto release folder and copy paste exe and config

Comment: Try copying everything in the release folder. I would expect there are dozens of dll files that are needed.

Comment: i did and all references aka dlls go into another folder zo i have got bin/executable and i have got bin/dependencies/dll files, where in visual studio every references is linked to dll inside the dependencies folder, but for some reason it doesn't look there, for all other drivers i have made it does work

Comment: I think release-build will split-up the two folders to make it easier for you to make a distribution package (for citrix, docker, gac, etc).  For your case, try copying the dlls into the same folder as your exe + config and try it.

Comment: yes that does work, every dll is in the same folder as the exe, however the problem is, due to our cms from another company the exe needs to be in the bin folder, the problem is i use multiple versions of system.net.http.formatting, where as the cms uses old 4.0 version whil I use version 5.7.2 which has been added to gac

Comment: Your exe will (by default) use the dll which is in the same folder as the exe. If it can't find a dll in that folder, it will check other places (system32, gac, etc). So make sure you have the required dlls in the same folder as your exe.

Comment: i have found the issue i didn't have any depedencyassemblies in the config file. usinf href's i have manage to find them :O